# trashed() retornando 'true' após restore()?

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-eloquent

Tenho um modelo `Manifestation` que utiliza `SoftDeletingTrait` para mantê-los inativos no banco e no `ManifestationController` tenho o seguinte método `destroy()`:

```
$manifestation = Manifestation::findOrFail($id);
$manifestation->closedBy()->associate(Auth::user());
$manifestation->save(); // save para marcar o usuário que encerrou
$manifestation->delete();
```

E se logo após utilizo `$manifestation->trashed()`, ele retorna `true`, e até aí está tudo correto. Porém, tenho também um método `restore()` no `controller`, com o seguinte:

```
$manifestation = Manifestation::withTrashed()->findOrFail($id);
$manifestation->closed_by_id = null;
$manifestation->save();
$manifestation->restore();
```

O problema é que se desta vez utilizo o `$manifestation->trashed()`, continuo recebendo `true` como resultado, mesmo o modelo não estando mais inativo.

1. Este comportamente é correto?
2. Existe alguma forma de contornar e fazer com que o `trashed()` volte a retornar `false` após o `restore()`?

Se não me engano deve haver uma `flag`, assim como a `exists` da classe `Eloquent` que possivelmente pode ser alterada, mas não consegui encontrá-la. Eu poderia, ao invés de usar o `trashed`, verificar se o valor de `deleted_at` é ***nulo***, mas quero evitar de fazê-lo, a menos que seja a última opção.

**Observações**:

- Ele volta a aparecer nos resultados de busca normalmente.
- Estou utilizando `Laravel 4.2` e não posso mudar.

Comment: Vitor estranho, porque não acontece isso, se você utilizou `restore()` o `trashed()` retorna `false` e se usou `delete()` retorna `true`, acabei de fazer um teste em um código antigo meu. O `exists` é um `boleano` que retorna true se existe o registro na base de dados, no caso seu ele sempre vai existir como true, só é falso para novos registros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois do comentário do [Virgilio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/177750/trashed-retornando-true-ap%C3%B3s-restore#comment367217_177750) descobri o que causou o problema.
Criei outro modelo com o mesmo *trait* e *controller* e o mesmo funcionou sem problemas, logo o problema estava no modelo `Manifestation`.

O que estava fazendo o resultado ser sempre *true* era que estava formatando o atributo `deleted_at` num formato mais legível para ser usado na *view* usando o comando `strftime`, e isso fazia com que ele **nunca ficasse nulo**, ficava a data inicial (1 de janeiro de 1970) mesmo estando nulo no banco, e o `trashed` simplesmente [verifica isso](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/SoftDeletingTrait.php#L99) (se o valor é nulo).

Para resolver, foi necessário apenas criar um novo atributo de outro nome chamando o `deleted_at`, formatando-o apenas no novo atributo e passar a utilizar ele a partir de então.

Estava algo similar a:

```
public function getDeletedAtAttribute($data){
  return strftime('%d/%m/%Y às %H:%M', strtotime($data));
}
```

Após a correção:

```
# getDeletedAtAttribute() removido

public function getClosedAtAttribute(){
  $data = $this->deleted_at;
  return strftime('%d/%m/%Y às %H:%M', strtotime($data));
}
```

Comment: Parabéns e realmente foi bem legal sua explicação +1; Reforçando a dica, não mexe nunca no padrão sempre tem a possibilidade no [tag:eloquent] de trabalhar as informações.